# Reading Serial Port in Perl

Tags: php, linux, perl, serial-port

I'm bit tired of reading serial port, using `Perl` first of all `Perl` is not my primary development tool, I'm from `PHP` background.
So please guide me in a right way. my intention is to read the data from a weight machine to a web page, I already did a lot of research on this topic.

The browser app cannot read serial port data directly so I choose the user end machine can be installed with a server (Apache) and do the task with PHP and web application can read the result using an Ajax call to `localhost url` the idea is working great on Linux machines but on windows PC it stuck.

I understand PHP can't read data from serial port in windows like Linux so I choose Perl to do the stuff. I did some search an got few codes and last 8 hours I'm fighting with that :(

```
#!E:\xampp\perl\bin\perl.exe
# The above line is perl execution path in xampp
# The below line tells the browser, that this script will send html content.
# If you miss this line then it will show "malformed header from script" error.

  print "Content-type: text/plain\n\n";
  # use strict; use warnings;
  use Win32;
  require 5.003;
  use Win32::SerialPort qw( :STAT 0.19 );
  print "here";
  $PortObj = new Win32::SerialPort ("COM3") || die "Can't open COM3: $^E\n";
  print "here";
  $PortObj->user_msg(ON);
  $PortObj->databits(8);
  $PortObj->baudrate(9600);
  $PortObj->parity("none");
  $PortObj->stopbits(1);
  $PortObj->handshake("rts");
  $PortObj->buffers(4096, 4096);

  $PortObj->error_msg(1);  # prints major messages like "Framing Error"
  $PortObj->user_msg(1);  

  $PortObj->write_settings || undef $PortObj;


  print "here";
  # $PortObj->save($Configuration_File_Name);
  $PortObj->read_interval(100);    # max time between read char (milliseconds)
  $PortObj->read_char_time(5);     # avg time between read char
  $PortObj->read_const_time(100);

   print "here";
   $string_in = $PortObj->read("200");

   print $string_in
  # $PortObj->baudrate(300);
  # $PortObj->restart($Configuration_File_Name);  # back to 9600 baud

  $PortObj->close || die "failed to close";
  undef $PortObj;
```

The code is not working but on forum and many other places it says working like [here](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/BBIRTH/SerialPort-0_10/SerialPort.pm) , [here](http://search.cpan.org/~bbirth/Win32-SerialPort-0.19/lib/Win32/SerialPort.pm), [this](http://www.perlmonks.org/bare/?node_id=682439) and [this](http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/16034.html).

Im unable to find what is this means "use Win32::SerialPort qw( :STAT 0.19 );"
is that something like importing that library with version number. ?

I'm already installed  Xampp with Perl and `activePerl Win32::serialport 0.22` and its API but when I run the code it return an error like

```
Error message:
End of script output before headers: serial.pl
```

500 Error

Any idea ??

**Solved**

For reading section I use the code below.

```
# warn "here";
  my ($ser) = @_;
  my ($numChars, $c);
  my $line = '';
  do {
    do {
      ($numChars, $c) = $PortObj->read(1);
      #print "$numChars read=$c\n";
    } while ($numChars < 1);
    # print $c;
    $line .= $c;
  } while ($c ne "\n");
   print $line;
```

The code works fine from CLI so I just put a PHP file to read the perl script and return the data.

Comment: *"The code is not working"* We need to know rather more than that. You should try running the program from the command line to see the output and any messages. Please also remove the comment from `use strict` and `use warnings`. Those are essential to save you from yourself.

Comment: You don't need the shebang line on Windows. Perl will ignore it except for any command-line switches that are included there

Comment: Also, if you `warn 'here'` instead of using `print`, perl will show the source line number as well so that you can distinguish between the calls. You can just `warn;` if you like, and perl will say `Warning: something's wrong at C:\Perl\source\program.pl line 8.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> use Win32::SerialPort qw( :STAT 0.19 );
> ```

This is the same as

```
use Win32::SerialPort ':STAT', '0.19';
```

The `:STAT` imports a number of useful status constants, and is explained [under ***Exports***](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::SerialPort#Exports) in the documentation for the module

The `0.19` is part of Perl, and is insisting that the version of `Win32::SerialPort` must be 0.19 or later. The current version is 0.22. If you change `0.19` to `0.23` then you will see the effect it has

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When I run the code from CLI it shows some error like declaration error for $PortObj and $string_in so I just declare it with my now it shows Bareword "ON" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at serial.pl line 17. that is in "$PortObj->user_msg(ON);" so i just commented that line.

Comment: Now its showing error @ Can't use string ("") as a symbol ref while "strict refs" in use at serial.pl line 40. that is   $string_in = $PortObj->input;   print $string_in , Im not sure how to print the  port value from device. Also this one major doubt it works from web page as well right ? Other wise no use for me to do the stuff, bcoz I need to get it from web application.

Comment: ok great I solved it :) thanks for the support When I run the script from browser it return error, So I run the script from PHP means PHP call a perl and return the result in browser works fine :)